# Why is my class selector not overriding tag selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So I've been coding for a week and I have googled for 30 min trying to find a solution. So excuse me if it's already been asked. I'm trying to write a summary of what I've learned after each lesson but it's not working!

```
<body> <center> h1> Module 40 </h1> </center>


<p>In this module I have learned on how to use the tag <!-- <div> ---> the purpose of this tag is to create a specific group whether it is images, headers, paragraphs, etc, which you can attribute seperate properties to so it is unaffected by tag selectors. by adding a class or ID to it. </p> <br>

<div class="p1">

 <p> Like for example this paragraph is inside a div called "p1". And I have added a specific font-size for this one compared to the previous paragraph which is affected by a <strong> tag </strong> selector instead of a <strong> class </strong> selector.
</p>

</div> 

</body>
```

And my CSS is this:

```
p
{
font-size: 15px;  
}

/*****class selector*****/
.p1
{
font-size: 20px;  
}
```

Shouldn't the class selector override the tag selector? Font size 15px is being applied to the whole text. It works if I add class="p1" to the second paragraph. But shouldn't this work if I add it to the div? Isn't that the purpose of having a div?

Comment: Before trying to gen an answer, pleas sort out your syntax., for example, in the first line, `h1>` needs to be `<h1>`. Also please don't use the `<center>` tag. as it is not supported on modern HTML. Use CSS to center the heading instead.

Answer (score 2):

Must be `.p1 p`

```css
p
{
font-size: 15px;  
}

/*****class selector*****/
.p1 p
{
font-size: 20px;  
}
```

```html
<p>In this module I have learned on how to use the tag <!-- <div> ---> the purpose of this tag is to create a specific group whether it is images, headers, paragraphs, etc, which you can attribute seperate properties to so it is unaffected by tag selectors. by adding a class or ID to it. </p> <br>

<div class="p1">

 <p> Like for example this paragraph is inside a div called "p1". And I have added a specific font-size for this one compared to the previous paragraph which is affected by a <strong> tag </strong> selector instead of a <strong> class </strong> selector.
</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of **Specificity**. **Specificity** is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property values are the **most relevant** to an element and, therefore, will be applied. Specificity is based on the matching rules which are composed of different sorts of [**CSS selectors**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Reference#Selectors).
You can find one of the most useful documentations here -

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

No because your paragraph is a child of .p1

All children inherit the styling of their parent (font-size:20px), but have the ability to override this (which you did by setting the paragraph styling to font-size: 15px)

You can read more about inheritance in CSS here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Your `<p>` tag is child of `<div>` tag, that's why its not working. Try adding the class to `<p>` tag